# Issue in iterating json response with ng-repeat in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm getting the response from http get and I'm not able to iterate the response in the view.
If I hardcode the response array outside the init function, the array can be iterated with ng-repeat in the view.
Please give a solution.. Below is the jsfiddle link for my problem

https://jsfiddle.net/ecvkz94o/2/

```
app.controller('cartCntr', function($scope,$http){

  $scope.pullProducts = function () {
                        $http.post("./phpProcessors/pullProductsViaAngular.php")  
       .success(function(data){  
            $scope.xy = data;  
       }) ; 
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "xy" has data that is given as the response of the post request according to your code, so you should do

```
<div ng-repeat="item in xy">
```

There is no sign of "products" in your js fiddle code.

Comment: even though I mention products, I face the same issue.  @Asim

Comment: Yes, I used scope.products only in my IDE, while copying to jsfiddle,  I made the mistake

Comment: @Muthu have you tried.... <div ng-repeat="item in xy" >
{{item.productName}} </div> ....and please post the output of "console.log(data);" done in the success part.

Comment: I just found the rootcause, checked in developer tools, after my post, font file is getting loaded, font file load is initiated by jquery.min.js, when I'm not loading jquey.min.js, it is working, I dont know how to stop this font load